# Close FIFO After Signal SIGTERM Received

Tags: c, signals, posix, named-pipes, sigterm

just this short question: how do we close the FIFO file if we receive the SIGTERM and exit.
If my file is a normal file, it works. But if it is a FIFO, it doesn't work.
Any ideas? Thanks :)

```
/**
    with the help of these guys, 
    it is not a good approach to write it, 
    though it works. close(fd) is pointless here.
**/

    FILE * myfile;
    int fd;
    void sig_handler(int signum) {
        if (signum == SIGTERM) {
            *close(fd);*
            fclose(myfile);
            printf("caught SIGTERM\n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }
    int main(void) {
        myfile = fopen("file", "w+");
        fd = open("myfifo", O_RDONLY);
        {
            struct sigaction act;
            memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));
            act.sa_handler = sig_handler;
            sigaction(SIGTERM, &act, 0);
        }
        for(;;)
            pause();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: There's no way it doesn't work. When a process exits, all its FDs are closed automatically. What makes you think that it doesn't work?

Comment: there are 4 signals being sent to it. Then I used valgrind to check, and there are 4 blocks not freed. I am quite not sure about it, because I either add close(fd) or not, the 4-block leak exists.

Comment: Are these not freed blocks definitely lost, or still reachable?

Comment: @Kaz It's definite lost.

Comment: are you getting a valid file desciptor on open?

Comment: @thejh @ n3rd4n1 Thanks you guys for the help :) very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the signal handler before opening the FIFO.  My Unix FIFO's are a little rusty :) but I suspect that the `open` is blocking for the peer to open it also.  So when you kill the process, it is not actually waiting inside your loop, but inside the `open` and so the signal handler does not go off.

On a different note, `fclose` in a signal handler is a bad idea. What if an I/O library operation is interrupted by the signal? The library is not reentrant from signal handlers. Only certain "async safe" functions can be used from signal handlers. Antoher one is `exit`, which does complicated things inside the library, many of which are not safe from an asynchronous signal handler. The `_exit` function should be used instead.

Worrying whether memory leaked, if you're causing the process to exit from a signal handler, is pointless, and impossible to get "right".  For one thing, `malloc` itself might be interrupted by the signal handler; it is not safe to call `free` to liberate anything.

Comment: Just tested it: `open(path, O_RDONLY)` on a FIFO that isn't opened for writing blocks.

Comment: I moved the fd=open(...) in between the local block and for loop, it doesn't make any difference :(

Comment: @thejh Yeah, this program just receive from that pipe.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Kaz! There are a lot of information in your answer.

Comment: So, now my understanding is: if I don't fclose the file here, where else should I do it? Actually that file in my program is a log file, so it will log the last information "program closed" when SIGTERM being caught and then close the file. If I don't do it over here, there will be one more leak.

Comment: @KittenTom Ah, now we are peeling the layers of the onion to get to the real problem.  You want the last bit of logging sent to the `FILE *` stream before the signal was received, ha.

Comment: If it's a signal that can be handled and ignored, what you can do is just set some global flag which indicates "termination has been requested". Then the main program can clean up and exit gracefully at the first opportunity.   If you want the last bit of logging close to an event such as a crash or the delivery of a fatal signal that cannot even be caught, then you have consider using a stream in line buffered mode which flushes every time a newline character is printed.  (Or even an unbuffered one, but line buffering is a compromise between being up to date, and efficiency).

Comment: @Kaz Thanks you very much for all the advices. The problem is caused by closing the file. It is cause by something else. ;)